# ML error starts off extremely low

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, keras

So I have some data that I need to train over that takes the form:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
normalization_1 (Normalizati (None, 13)                3         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 14        
=================================================================
Total params: 17
Trainable params: 14
Non-trainable params: 3
_________________________________________________________________
```

The output starts at an extremely low error and then decreases. I am worried about this because I'm so used to seeing a model start off badly and then get better over time. I feel this is too good to be true and hence I think I've done something wrong and this model won't generalize well.

Here is my code:

```
normalizer3 = Normalization(input_shape=[train_x3.shape[1],], axis=None)
normalizer3.adapt(train_x3.axes[0])

linear_model3 = Sequential([
    normalizer3,
    Dense(units=1)
])

linear_model3.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='mean_absolute_error')

history3 = linear_model3.fit(
    train_x3,
    train_y3,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=128,
    verbose=0,
    #callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)],
    validation_data=(test_x3, test_y3))

plt.plot(history3.history['loss'], label='Loss')
plt.plot(history3.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('ADAM Optimizer with LR=0.001')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Mean Absolute Error')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
```

And here is my output:

[image]

Comment: How much data do you have? Does decreasing the learning rate change this behavior?

Comment: About 45k data points. Increasing the LR doesn't change the behaviour, just where it starts

Comment: What does **decreasing** the learning rate do? // Is the model predicting different values for each input, or are the predictions basically tightly grouped around the median of the target?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I switched those around! Decreasing does actually seem to give the kind of output I'd expect. Thanks for that

Comment: Feel free to write up this finding as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP stated in a comment that decreasing the size of the learning rate achieved the kind of progression in the loss that they were looking for:

> Decreasing does actually seem to give the kind of output I'd expect. Thanks for that

Tuning the learning rate (optimizer step size) is an important part of estimating a neural network. More information can be found in high-quality textbooks about neural networks such as Goodfellow's *Deep Learning.*